# Scrollview  Delay / Lag in pageControl

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, scrollview

We are building an iPad catalog application with images. The image scrolling is very smooth (no delay)  using scrollview, however the corresponding the pageControl (small dots at the bottom) take an extra 1.5 sec approximately. Please see attached screenshot.

Is there a way to minimize this lag/delay? Thank you for your help.[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Gurus it will be great to get your help on this. Bump!

Comment: Where is the code that updates the page control?

Answer (score 2):

What I'm getting from your question is horizontal scrolling (using the Page Control) is lagging/choppy. Run your app on the simulator, and from the 'Debug' menu, click 'Color Blended Layers'. This option will highlight any transparent object in red. Optimally, everything would be green. Try making everything red green by setting its background color to the background color of its superview, if that is possible and setting the view's `opaque` setting to `YES`. Good luck. For more information: check out the [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH14-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, in your code, when you move to a new page? Are you pulling down any data, images, etc... ?

On a side note, I would look into both the ScrollView and PageControl to see how they rendered. It could be ScrollView is using Bitmap images once the views are rendered and PageControl is not.